# Attach images in mail without option "show images" in mail

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I send e-mail with PHP as HTML. I can add images for this mail for two ways:

1. Add to html - `<img src="http://www.mysite.com/image.png" />`
2. Use PHP Mailer and use option `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($src, 'test');` and `<img src="cid:test">`

but in both ways if i receive mail then i must click "show images". Is possible add images to mail so that images immediately were visible?
I can use PHP Mailer.

Comment: No this is not possible. The only workaround I'm aware of is to build the image with html which will is only feasible if the image is very simple.

Comment: If the image contains some important information, you should make sure you are including an `AltBody` which is a plain text alternative in PHP Mailer so that the information in the graphic can be seen by users preferring to not see `html` based email

Answer (score 0):

"Show Images" is a security feature of the email client that you are using. By default, email messages have no features such as this. Instead, it is implemented by the email provider or application that you are using. Typically, any untrusted senders will have images and other attachments blocked by default to protect your privacy and security.

For instance, someone could create a page (aspx, php, etc.) that would stream an image. They could include this image in an email. If you view the image, they could grab information such as your IP address which could allow them to potentially attack or break into your system.

My recommendation would be to add yourself to a safe senders list. However, keep in mind that this is done on an account basis, and anyone else who receives your messages would have to do the same thing. Since each email provider or client has their own rules, there is no way to easily enable this across the board.

You could also try to use a big third party email service provider, which may be on 'trusted' lists with many email providers. However, once again you will have to do more research to see if this is an option and how this would work for you.